# ASP.NET MVC persist value of dropdown on post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am displaying a list of records  on a View. And also have a dropdown list which controls the number of records to be displayed on page with option say 10, 20 and 50.

To achieve this I am triggering my controller action on change of drop down using jquery change event. Following is my java script code :-

```
$('select[name="pagingCount"]').on('change', function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var pagingCount = $('select[name="pagingCount"]').val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")?pagingCount=' + pagingCount;
            window.location = url;
        });
```

It works fine. But I want to keep selected value after page reload. I am not sure how to do this? Since drop down doesn't belong to any model property. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set value of the dropdown based upon the `pagingCount` parameter in the url

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
$(function(){
  $('select[name="pagingCount"]').val(getParameterByName("pagingCount"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably already taking the pagingCount parameter in your action method.

All you need to do now is pass that value into you View (Preferably by setting the property in your ViewModel) and having the view set the selected value in the drop down list.

Comment: But that drop down doesn't belong to any ViewModel property. I can pass pagingCount back to view but don't know how to use that to select dropdown value.

Comment: How are you currently passing in the list to bind to the drop down? ViewModel, ViewData, ViewBag?? Which ever method you are using, you should be able to add another property for the pagingCount. You might want to include the code for the Action and View so we can get a better idea.